# Angular 2 json file linked and html showing but no data

Tags: json, angular, interface

I have been able to link an external json file and loop through some of the nested objects with ngFor as some of the the html is being put out on the website, but there is no data showing. If have been trying to put the data in an interface but it is still not showing up...

This is my module:

```
import { NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Service } from './app.service';

import { AppComponent } from './component.app';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        Service
    ]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from './app.service';
import { Test } from './tests';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './assets/partials/component-app.html',
    styleUrls: ['./assets/css/component-app.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    tests: any;

    constructor(private service : Service){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
        this.tests = data;
        })
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable() 
export class Service {

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getData(): Observable<Test[]>{
    return this._http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
        .map(res => <Test[]>res.json().test_cases);
        .map(res => <Test[]>res.json().test_steps);
  }  
}
```

The data interface:

```
export class Test {
     test_run_id: string;
     app_name: string;
     time_stamp: string;
     test_cases:  {
        test_name: string,
        status: string,
        test_steps: {
            step_name: string,
            screenshot: blob,
            launch_times: array,
            memory: array,
            cpu: array
        }
    }
}
```

The json:

```
{
"test_run_id":  "A233-CA92-3293-B9AA",
"app_name": "Chewy.com",
"time_stamp": "2018-01-20T12:00:00Z",
"test_cases": [
    {
        "test_name": "View dog bone",
        "status": true,
        "test_steps": [
            {
                "step_name": "Click Dog Category",
                "screenshot": "file1.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    100,
                    134,
                    123
                ],
                "memory": [
                    896,
                    945,
                    1023
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    1.1,
                    1.4,
                    5.7
                ]
            },
            {
                "step_name": "Click Treats",
                "screenshot": "file2.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    345,
                    441,
                    286
                ],
                "memory": [
                    1320,
                    1206,
                    1456
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    12.1,
                    13.4,
                    12.7
                ]
            },
            {
                "step_name": "Click Bone",
                "screenshot": "file3.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    342,
                    1456,
                    326
                ],
                "memory": [
                    1420,
                    1420,
                    1420
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    3.1,
                    4.4,
                    2.9
                ]
            },
            {
                "step_name": "Verify Bone is displayed",
                "screenshot": "file4.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    103,
                    124,
                    123
                ],
                "memory": [
                    1502,
                    1499,
                    1538
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    2.1,
                    3.4,
                    3.7
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "test_name": "View cat toy",
        "status": false,
        "test_steps": [
            {
                "step_name": "Click Cat Category",
                "screenshot": "file5.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    108,
                    194,
                    163
                ],
                "memory": [
                    996,
                    945,
                    1223
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    2.2,
                    2.4,
                    2.1
                ]
            },
            {
                "step_name": "Click Toys",
                "screenshot": "file6.png",
                "launch_times": [
                    445,
                    408,
                    386
                ],
                "memory": [
                    920,
                    1132,
                    995
                ],
                "cpu": [
                    2.1,
                    3.2,
                    2.1
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="tested-app" *ngFor = "let item of tests">
<h2>----<span> {{ item.app_name }} </span>----</h2>
<p class="time"> Time: <span> {{item.time_stamp}} </span> </p>
<section class="flexWrap">
    <div class="module" *ngFor="let subItem of item.test_cases">
        <h3> {{ subItem.test_name }} </h3>
        <p class="status"> {{subItem.status}} </p>
        <div class="step" *ngFor = "let testStep of subItem.test_steps">
            <h4>{{testStep.step_name}}</h4>
            <img src="../assets/images/{{testStep.screenshot}}">
            <div class="results">
                <p>Launch Times:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{testStep.launch_times[0]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.launch_times[1]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.launch_times[2]}}</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Memory:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{testStep.memory[0]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.memory[1]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.memory[2]}}</li>
                </ul>
                <p>CPU</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>{{testStep.cpu[0]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.cpu[1]}}</li>
                    <li>{{testStep.cpu[2]}}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section></section>
```

Comment: First of all, your interface is not correct: test_cases and test_steps are arrays rather than objects. Second of all, please add your html file and possible some error messages from the console, if you have any.

Comment: HTML added to original post... No error messages in the console. It is outputting the HTML of the first ngFor. The h2 and <p class="time"> is showing, just not the data. The rest of the HTML nor data is showing,

Comment: I'm assuming that you mapping is not correct: you are calling `.json()` method twice which is unnecessary. Also, why do you need the second `.map` at all? test_cases already contain all the data that you might need. Try removing `.map(res => <Test[]>res.json().test_steps);`

Comment: Oh, in that case you don't need any `.map` operators at all, with Angular 5 you don't even need to do the response.json() conversion, just have the subscribe. Your html looks fine to me.

Comment: I do need those, without them nothing is showing up.. This is not Angular 5.

Comment: just try 

getData(): Observable<Test[]>{
    return this._http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
        .map(res => <Test[]>res.json());
}

Comment: As for .map(res => <Test[]>res.json().test_steps);
Then how do I get to the third level nested object though..?

Comment: you have the entire structure in you `this.tests` and you are already parsing it in your template

Comment: No that's what I had before and I had a lot of errors:
28 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: I had it with just res.json() and that's when I had the 
28 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your are getting an Array of tests? From the "first part of json" snippet it looks like there is only one test, which is an object that has meny test_cases

Comment: There is one test indeed, with a bunch of test cases, and each test case had a bunch of test steps...

Comment: Can you check the answer and see if it works?

Comment: No didn't work, back to the error I was having before this:

28 caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: Is the error still the same? Has anything changed?

Comment: Could you maybe post your entire HTML for the component and the entire json?

Comment: No the error is not the same, it broke even more. If I leave it as is (in the original post) it at least puts out the first parts of HTML (no data though) but if I change it to your answer I get an error that I got before I added my version of the map (with the .test_cases etc)

Comment: That error is not that scary, it simply means that you are trying to iterate over an object with ngFor rather than over an array. That's why I'm asking you to post the full html and json to help you find the discrepancy. What's the point of avoiding the error when you have no data?

Comment: lol true.... it just seemed I was getting somewhere with some output instead of an error.

Anyway, I posted the full HTML and JSON

Comment: So you are saying that you tried editing the html the way I posted in the answer and you are still getting the error?

Comment: Did you remove the first ngFor from the section tag?

Comment: Look at the updated answer, I posted a code snippet, proving that the template changes I suggested were correct

Comment: Thanks for upvoting! Could you also consider accepting the answer?

Comment: It is not quite working yet, I get the error: 22 caused by: Cannot read property 'test_cases' of undefined

Comment: Getting closer though!

Comment: Try adding *ngIf to the outer tag: `<section *ngIf="tests" class="tested-app">`

Comment: YES!!! It's working!!! OMG thanks!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion I'm pretty sure this should work:

Change your getData method like so:

```
getData(): Observable<Test[]>{
    return this._http.get('./assets/data/data.json')
        .map(res => <Test>res.json();
  }
```

And then remove the first ngFor in your template:

```
<section *ngIf="tests" class="tested-app">
   <h2>----<span> {{ tests.app_name }} </span>----</h2>
   <p class="time"> Time: <span> {{tests.time_stamp}} </span> </p>
   <section class="flexWrap">
       <div class="module" *ngFor="let testCase of tests.test_cases">
           <h3> {{ testCase.test_name }} </h3>
           <p class="status"> {{testCase.status}} </p>
           <div class="step" *ngFor = "let testStep of testCase.test_steps">
               <h4>{{testStep.step_name}}</h4>
               <img src="../assets/images/{{testStep.screenshot}}">
```

**UPDATE:**
Please have a look at this working sample. No errors in the console with the changes in the template.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duzb7z